# send multiple object or list object from Spring Boot to Angular

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

With AngularJS, I knew that Spring Boot can use model.attribute to return many objects or list object same below:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello")
    public String home(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, Model model) {        

            model.addAttribute("Authorization", "test string");

            return "/index";
    }  
}
```

But don't know how to make the same in Spring Boot and Angular 8???
Spring Boot + Angular 8 and Spring Boot + AngularJS are the same?
Anyone can help me??? Thank you?

Comment: You can add **produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE** to your @RequestMapping tag and then return a list from the method. In this case, your angular will receive a list of JSON objects and you can parse it over there.

Comment: Oh. This does not have my problem. For example, I have 2 objects from 2 classes. And I want to have a function in a controller to return 2 objects. How I make it in Spring Boot and Angular, somethings like model.attribute in Spring Boot and AngularJS

Comment: @Tina Your controller currently returns a view, i.e. an HTML page. Angular (just as AngularJS) applications consists in having the view handled by JavaScript, inside the browser, and in requesting **data**, as JSON, from the server. So your question doesn't make much sense. You should write rest controllers, returning data, not controllers returning views.

Comment: hi tina i will help with this please let me know more what you trying to do here

Answer (score 0):

When you using angular then you get JSON response when to do HTTP request so please try this,
and Also add Cross Origin at your rest controller to communication between cross-server

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello")
    public PayloadRespons home(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, Model model) { 


   PayloadRespons payload = new PayloadRespons();
   payload.setAuthorization = "test string"
           // model.addAttribute("Authorization", "test string");

            return payload;
    }  
}

class PayloadRespons{

private String Authorization;

.... some more which you have 

.... Getter and Settter 
}
```